# How can I get a particular editor space in python?

Tags: scripting

Right now, to set the current action before rendering, I am doing this to find the dopesheet editor space:

```
dope_sheet = None
for space in bpy.context.area.spaces:
    if space.type == 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR':
        dope_sheet = space
        break
else
    print('CANNOT FIND DOPESHEET_EDITOR IN bpy.context.area.spaces!!!')
    return
```

Is there some easier way to get the dopesheet editor than searching spaces for it?

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't seem right, it should be

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR':
        space_data = area.spaces.active
        break
else:
    space_data = None

if space_data is not None:
    pass
```

To avoid searching for the right area (which may or may not exist in current screen layout), it's possible to change `bpy.context.area.type` temporarily to the type you require.

However, I'm pretty sure what you actually want to do is:

```
bpy.context.object.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions['The Name']
```

Comment: When I iterate over area in bpy.context.sceen.areas, I don't find a dopesheet editor if there isn't one currently on screen.  When I iterate over bpy.context.area.spaces, I am finding a dopesheet editor regardless of this, but maybe something else is wrong with it?

Comment: I do want to apply the animation to everything, not just the active object (isn't that what bpy.context.object.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions['The Name'] would do?)

Comment: I'm not confident of the reliability of iterating spaces, because there is usually just one when I run some test code (mostly active space only, so of the editor type the cursor is over). My above code tells Blender to use the specified action for the context object (could be any object). It looked to me as though it's identical to setting the action in the dopesheet editor space, but I could be mistaken. Nonetheless, you could iterate all objects and assign that action if that is what you want.